# How can I send a message to my cellphone when someone logs onto my computer?

Tags: windows-7

I'm looking for a software that can be installed on my computer that sends a notification with details to my cell phone, if I or others log in.

Comment: This article might help http://lifehacker.com/5941294/use-windows-task-scheduler-to-get-email-notifications-when-someone-logs-into-your-computer

Comment: Software recommendation questions are off-topic.  See the [FAQ] for details.

Answer (score 2):

Android has a pretty cool solution, see [this article](http://www.pcworld.com/article/255980/6_essential_desktop_apps_to_make_your_android_phone_device_a_work_or_play_powerhouse.html). It also depends on your phone. If you have an iPhone you might need to try something else. If you are worried about physical security, why dont you just create different accounts for every user?

Comment: From a quick read of the article, I don't see how any of the 6 apps listed accomplish what the OP is asking for. Perhaps you could clarify a bit exactly which app you mean by "a pretty cool solution"?

Comment: From what I understood from OP, I was refrencing the Apps called:  Android Notifier and Lookout Mobile Security.  IMHO, I think that this is more of a User Access / Account question.

Comment: As best as I can tell, Android Notifier brings notifications from the phone to the computer, and Lookout Mobile Security is for tracking the phone. The OP is asking for something that will send a notification to his phone if someone logs on to his computer.

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of anything offhand that would do this (though i could have sworn I'd seen it in a movie ;p), but it should be fairly trivial to throw something like this together.

In order to run a task at startup or logon you can use task scheduler. In windows XP you only have the option to run the task at startup, but in windows you can run it at login as well.

You'd then need to actually contact your phone - you could probably throw together a script with [blat](http://www.blat.net/) to send an e mail, or run some other custom software. It wouldn't be realtime, but close enough.

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/123568/how-to-get-email-notifications-whenever-someone-logs-into-your-computer/ one example of an e mail script. I'll update my answer when more awake